# how to link dll in qt

Tags: c++, qt, dll, shared-libraries

I have an external library both in .dll and .lib and I have its .h file
library name is 'MTK_288_K001'[.dll|.lib|.h]

Here is my qt.pro:

```
QT += core gui serialport

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++14 static staticlib

TARGET = kiosk

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    serialport.cpp

RESOURCES += resources.qrc

win32: RC_ICONS = icon.ico

FORMS += mainwindow.ui

HEADERS += mainwindow.h \
    serialport.h

win32 {
    LIBS += -lMTK_288_K001
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lMTK_288_K001
}

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/MTK_288_K001.lib
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/MTK_288_K001.lib
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include "MTK_288_K001.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MTK288KROpen("COM1");

    qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "1");
    QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("./plugins");
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mw;
    mw.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MTK_288_K001.h

```
#define Bad_CommOpen -101
#define Bad_CommClose -105

#define OK                  0
#define ERR                 -1

#define Parameter_Error     -2
#define UpLoadErrorData     -3
#define UpLoadTimeOut       -4 
#define UpLoadCancel        -5 

#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY GetSysVerion(char *strVerion);
HANDLE APIENTRY MTK288KUOpen();
int APIENTRY MTK288KUClose(HANDLE ComHandle);

int APIENTRY MTK288KUMultOpen(HANDLE DeviceHdlData[],int *DeviceNumbers);
int APIENTRY MTK288KUMultClose(HANDLE DeviceHdlData[],int DeviceNumbers);

int APIENTRY GetDeviceCapabilities(HANDLE ComHandle, int *_InputReportByteLength, int *_OutputReportByteLength);
int APIENTRY ReadACKReport(HANDLE ComHandle,  BYTE _ReportData[],BYTE _ReportLen);
int APIENTRY ReadUpReport(HANDLE ComHandle,  BYTE _ReportData[],BYTE _ReportLen);
int APIENTRY ReadReport(HANDLE ComHandle,  BYTE _ReportData[],BYTE _ReportLen);

int APIENTRY WriteReport(HANDLE ComHandle,  BYTE _ReportData[],BYTE _ReportLen);
int APIENTRY USB_ExeCommand(HANDLE ComHandle,BYTE TxCmCode,BYTE TxPmCode,int TxDataLen,BYTE TxData[],BYTE *RxReplyType,BYTE *RxStCode1,BYTE *RxStCode0,int *RxDataLen,BYTE RxData[]);


HANDLE APIENTRY MTK288KROpen(char *Port);
HANDLE APIENTRY MTK288KROpenWithBaut(char *Port, unsigned int Baudrate);
int APIENTRY MTK288KRClose(HANDLE ComHandle);
int APIENTRY RS232_ExeCommand(HANDLE ComHandle,BYTE TxCmCode,BYTE TxPmCode,int TxDataLen,BYTE TxData[],BYTE *RxReplyType,BYTE *RxStCode1,BYTE *RxStCode0,int *RxDataLen,BYTE RxData[]);


int APIENTRY USB_UpTrackData(HANDLE ComHandle,BYTE tracks,BYTE ReadMode,BYTE _WaitTime,BYTE *RxReplyType,int *_CardDataLen,BYTE _CardData[]);
int APIENTRY USB_Cancel_UpTrackData(HANDLE ComHandle);

int APIENTRY RS232_UpTrackData(HANDLE ComHandle,BYTE tracks,BYTE ReadMode,BYTE _WaitTime,BYTE *RxReplyType,int *_CardDataLen,BYTE _CardData[]);
int APIENTRY RS232_Cancel_UpTrackData(HANDLE ComHandle);
```

When I build the project qt gives me this:

```
D:\kiosk\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `MTK288KROpen(char*)@4'
```

How can I tell qt to find this function in external libraries?

Comment: If MTK_288_K001 is a C library, you need to add `extern "C" { }` around `#include "MTK_288_K001.h"`. Anyway you can use dependency walker to see the symbols in  MTK_288_K001.dll and search for "MTK288KROpen" or something similar.

Comment: remove **static staticlib**

Comment: even by removing `static staticlib` or `extern "C" { }` around `#include "MTK_288_K001.h"`, qt still giving me that error. and `'MTK288KROpen' `exists in dll file

Answer (score 0):

From your comment you have the symbol `MTK288KROpen` defined in your DLL.
However the linker complains that `MTK288KROpen(char*)@4` is not defined.

This is likely caused by a "bad" declaration of the `HANDLE APIENTRY MTK288KROpen(char *Port)` function.

As said in my comment adding `extern "C"` should fix the issue by making the linker looking for the `MTK288KROpen` symbol and not for `MTK288KROpen(char*)@4`.

I suspect that the suggestion I made earlier in my comment to add `extern "C" { }` around `#include "MTK_288_K001.h"` did not work because you already include `MTK_288_K001.h` in `mainwindow.h`.

To be sure add `extern "C"` to the `MTK288KROpen` declaration in `MTK_288_K001.h`, like this:

```
...
// This is C++ code so you cannot compile MTK_288_K001.dll anymore with this change, but it should work with your Qt app
extern "C" HANDLE APIENTRY MTK288KROpen(char *Port);
HANDLE APIENTRY MTK288KROpenWithBaut(char *Port, unsigned int Baudrate);
...
```

The linker shouldn't complain about `MTK288KROpen` anymore, but might still complains about other functions.

If your still have an error for `MTK288KROpen` please tell me if it is a new one so I can update my answer accordingly. And also tell what is the value of `APIENTRY`.

If it worked, you have 2 options depending if you can edit `MTK_288_K001.h`.

If you can edit it, add `extern "C"` to it like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

[...]

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If you cannot, create an intermediate file `MTK_288_K001_CPP.h` and use it instead of `MTK_288_K001.h` in your Qt project:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "MTK_288_K001.h"
}
```

Comment: this is my code i tried what you said. [github](https://github.com/behnejad/kiosk.git)

Comment: The `extern "C"` was needed, but it looks like `MTK288K001.lib` does not match `MTK288K001.dll`, removing `MTK288K001.lib` allows the project to compile and link.

Comment: problem fixed. and another problem appears. program cannot run after build. qt gives `The program has unexpectedly finished.`

Comment: Use a debugger to see where it crashed. From your code, it can be caused by `MTK288KROpen("COM1")`, because string literals are `const char *` but the function takes a `char *` and may try to change the string literal.

Comment: even with this function which gives no argument `MTK288KUOpen()` program cannot run. i run with qt debugger and it gave me `During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.` i copied dll file to debug directory but it does not have any effect on runtime.

Comment: If your program exit during startup is does not matter which function you call as they are not called anyway. This is likely caused by a missing or invalid DLL or an issue during initialization of static variables.